# js regex replace match in certain paragraph

Tags: regex, lookbehind

```
---
title: test
date: 2018/10/17
description: some thing
---
```

I want to replace what's behind `date` if it's between `---`, in this case `2018/10/17`. How to do that with regex in JS?

So far I've tried;

```
/(?<=---\n)[\s\S]*date.+(?=\n)/
```

but it only works when date is the first line after `---`

Comment: What is your regex 'machine'/programming language? Also, show what you have tried.

Comment: @PoulBak Javascript on server side. I've tried `/(?<=---\n)[\s\S]*date.+(?=\n)/` but it only works when `date` is the first line after `---`

Comment: Use a two-steps approach: Grab blocks of `---` on both sides and look for a date line within.

Comment: @Jan Thanks, I know it's gonna work, I just want know whether there is a one-step solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure Javascript supports look behind at all, but if your environment supports it, you can try this regex:

```
/(?<=---[\s\S]+)(?<=date: )[\d/]+(?=[\s\S]+---)/
```

It looks behind for '---' followed by anything, then it looks behind for 'date: ' before it matches digits or slash one or more times, followed by a look ahead for anything followed by '---'.

Now you can easily replace the match with a new date.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Well it does not unfortunately so this won't work in JS.

Comment: I don't know about server side JS, seems he had tried (also Chrome supports it).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible though imo not advisable:

```
(^---)((?:(?!^---)[\s\S])+?^date:\s*)(.+)((?:(?!^---)[\s\S])+?)(^---)
```

This needs to be replaced by `$1$2substitution$4$5`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/1WfOuR/1).

---

Broken down this reads

```
(^---)                    # capture --- -> group 1
(
    (?:(?!^---)[\s\S])+?  # capture anything not --- up to date:
    ^date:\s*
)
(.+)                      # capture anything after date
(
    (?:(?!^---)[\s\S])+?) # same pattern as above
(^---)                    # capture the "closing block"
```

Please consider using the afore-mentioned two-step approach as this regex is not going to be readable in a couple of weeks (and the `JS` engine does not support a verbose mode).

Answer (score 2):

Without using a positive lookbehind, you could use 2 capturing groups and use those in the replacement like $1replacement$2

`(^---[\s\S]+?date: )\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}([\s\S]+?^---)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QBGXzn/1)

**Explanation**

- `(` Capturing group

  - `^---[\s\S]+?date:` Match from the start of the line 3 times a `-` followed by matching any 0+ times any character non greedy and then `date:`
- `)` Close first capturing group
- `\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}` Match a date like pattern (Note that this does not validate a date itself)
- `(` Capturing group

  - `[\s\S]+?^---` Match any 0+ times any character non greedy followed by asserting the start of the line and match 3 times `-`
- `)` Close capturing group

```js
const regex = /(^---[\s\S]+?date: )\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}([\s\S]+?^---)/gm;
const str = `---
title: test
date: 2018/10/17
description: some thing
---`;
const subst = `$1replacement$2`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```